# cleaning up rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using devise with few changes to the controllers and have the following routes defined.

```
  devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations, :sessions]

  devise_scope :user do
    resource :registration,
      only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],
      path: 'users',
      path_names: { new: 'sign-up' },
      controller: 'registrations',
    as: :user_registration do
      get :cancel
    end
    get 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'sign-in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'sign-out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get "sign-up" => "registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  end
```

resulting in the following duplicate routes:

```
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign-up(.:format)           registrations#new
new_user_registration GET    /sign-up(.:format)                 registrations#new
```

How do i clean my route file that the duplication does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure, postet as answer for format:

I think that the redundancy cames from here:

devise_scope **:user** do
resource :registration,
**only: [:new**, :create, :edit, :update],
path: 'users',
path_names:   **new: 'sign-up'**  ,

this makes the

```
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign-up(.:format)           registrations#new
```

and

```
get "sign-up" => "registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
```

adds

```
new_user_registration GET    /sign-up(.:format)                 registrations#new
```

so leave one of them

Comment: This works. Removed the `only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],` as my goal was to make the sign-up link work as /sign-up